# Negative time in a simple harmonic motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

> The displacement of a particle in a time $t$ is given by the expression $x=4 \cos(3.0\pi t+\pi)$. if at the time $t$ the velocity of the particle is $26.66\ \mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}$. What is the value of $t$?

I'm having problems to solve this exercises. The time is supposed to be $0.25\ \mathrm{s}$ but I can't solve it.

If I have this:

$26.66= - 4 \times3.0\pi \sin(3.0\pi t+\pi)$.

Then:

$\arcsin(-\frac{26.66}{4\times3.0\pi}) = 3.0\pi t+\pi$

$\frac{-0.785-\pi}{3.0\pi} =  t$

$ -0.41 =  t$

I can't figure out why I'm getting: first a different time, and second, a negative time.

Has something to do with the phase?

Comment: Hint: There are an infinite number of solutions to $\sin\left(x\right)=a$ so long as $-1<a<1$.

Comment: @ThePhoton I assume you meant to write $-1 \le a \le 1$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sin(3\pi t+\pi +2n\pi)=\sin(3\pi t+\pi)$ for any integer $n$, reorganize the first to
$$
\sin(3\pi(t+2n/3)+\pi)\, .
$$
Thus, if you have found a value for $t$, any value $t_n=t+2n/3$ for $n=\pm 1,\pm 2,\ldots$ will produce the same value for $v$ as $t$.

Answer (score 0):

You have an algebra error - and a missing $2k\pi$ term where $k$ needs to be a negative integer.

Starting with 
$$ \arcsin(-v/12\pi)=3\pi t+ \pi +2k\pi$$ 
$$\frac{1}{\pi} \arcsin(-v/12\pi)=3t+1+2k$$
$$\Big[\frac{1}{\pi} \arcsin(-v/12\pi)-1-2k\Big]=3t$$
$$t=\frac{1}{3}\Big[\frac{1}{\pi} \arcsin(-v/12\pi)-1-2k\Big]$$

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but while checking for the answer I found that $$x=4\cos (3\pi t - \pi)$$ should be the equation to get the answer as $t=0.25s$.

$$\pmb {\underline {\text {Let's see how}}}$$
Since
$$x=4\cos (3.0 \pi t - \pi)$$
$$\Rightarrow v=-12 \pi \sin (3.0 \pi t - \pi)$$
$$\Rightarrow 26.66 =-12 \pi \sin (3.0 \pi t - \pi)$$ (Now carefully solve in radians) 
And the answer is $t=0.25s$.